# Control access to REST-actions of my Gerrit plugin

Tags: gerrit

I'm writing a plugin for Gerrit 2.11.3. Within the plugin I have REST-actions in the BRANCH-context. Something like this:

```
install(new RestApiModule() {
    protected void configure() {

      post(BranchResource.BRANCH_KIND, "my-cool-action").to(MyCoolAction.class);
      ...

    }
}
```

It turned out, that in order to call my action over the REST-API

```
$ curl  ...  -X POST http://localhost:8080/a/projects/TestProject/branches/master/my-plugin~my-cool-action
```

the user needs "write" permissions on the project.

My questions are:

- how can I controll required permissions for my actions?
- how can I make an action PUBLIC?
  (allow it to be called without authentication and without "/a/" part in the REST-Url)